# Android minus Margin/Padding

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I work with android, I want to draw  design like this

[image]

There are two LinearLayuots ( blue and white ), I want add picture their borders, I have tryied to use minus  margin but not work

Can Anybody help me?

Comment: Post the layout code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `RelativeLayout` for your layout's parent and then add two `LinearLayout` and one `ImageView` or `Button`. and set your Button (or ImageView,etc) to centerVertical and alignParentLeft and give some marginLeft to it!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.neo.myapplication.MyActivity">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/aboveLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        ></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/aboveLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"></LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="#013032"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="#ff3e7730"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstRow"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my panels is too big image is small